# AngularJS auto redirection renders in partial view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, partial-views

A site using JAVA REST full service and Angular.

On service exception need to auto-logout and redirection to LogOn. On exception, logout will fire, full LogOn-page will be rendered in partial view, instead of refreshing the "parent/top" window. So the entire site is mirrored in the partial view (like often happens when using frames). The is no frame or iframe usage on the site though.

use window.location.href for redirecting to logon page

Note: The address bar still has application url  and not logon url

Comment: a [mcve] would be great.

Comment: What is the actual question here?  This just looks like a requirements list.

Comment: Point is the logon page is viewed in partial view (inside the application) and its not redirected to new page